# Sybase query error using Spring JDBCTemplate in java

Tags: sybase, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

I am trying to run a query on a Sybase database using Spring JDBCTemplate (org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate)

Following is my code:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Table_A a WHERE a.col1 LIKE ? AND a.col2 LIKE ?";
getJdbcTemplate().query(query , new String[] { stringParam1, stringParam2}, new MyMapper());
```

Above code throws this error:

```
 Exception occurred org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [SELECT * FROM Table_A a WHERE a.col1 LIKE ? AND a.col2 LIKE ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: 
Function LIKE invoked with wrong number or type of argument(s).
```

The same query works fine on sql server. Any idea what should be done differently for Sybase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encapsulate your question marks in quotes for Sybase to treat it as a `char` value, which is the argument type expected in the query.